# TideSDK - package app larger than 2gb

Tags: wix, tidesdk

I'm trying to generate an installer (package the app) for my application, but it contains a lot of video files which make the total size of the whole project 2.5GB.

TideSDK throws the following error everytime I try to package:

```
light.exe : error LGHT0296 : An error (E_FAIL) was returned while adding files to a CAB file. This most commonly happens when creating a CAB file 2 GB or larger. Either reduce the size of your installation package, raise Media/@CompressionLevel to a higher compression level, or split your installation package's files into more than one CAB file. Done packaging!
```

It gives me 3 solutions, however, I have no idea how I could raise the media/compression level nor how to divide the installation package's files into more than one CAB.

Anyone went through this same issue? :(

Comment: Wix linker (light.exe) throws the above error, not TideSDK, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your .wxs file should be a line similar to this:

```
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
```

You need to add another one with different Id, like this:

```
<Media Id="2" Cabinet="media2.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
```

And then specify DiskId attribute in your Component or File elements:

```
<File Id="FirstLargeFile.avi" Name="FirstLargeFile.avi" DiskId="1" />
<File Id="SecondLargeFile.avi" Name="SecondLargeFile.avi" DiskId="2" />
```

Comment: Probably not applicable, if TideSDK incapsulates all installation logic.